# vhdl error in a for loop. Erro 10500

Tags: vhdl

I'm doing a simple ula in vhdl. In the sum operation get a message error

Error:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at rjr_neander.vhd(30) near text "for";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("for" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at rjr_neander.vhd(34) near text "loop";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("loop" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"
```

Code:

```
entity ula is
port(
        inputA, inputB: in bit_vector(0 to 7);
        output: out bit_vector(0 to 7)
        );
end ula;  


architecture sum8bits of ula is
        signal cout : bit_vector(0 to 6);
begin 
        -- Half adder do bit 0
        output(0) <= inputA(0) xor inputB(0);
        cout(0) <= inputA(0) and inputB(0);
        for indice in 1 to 7 loop
        -- iteracao para fazer o full adder dos 7 bits restantes
            output(indice) <= inputA(indice) xor inputB(indice) xor cout(indice-1);
            cout(indice) <= (inputA(indice) and inputB(indice)) or (inputA(indice) and cout(indice-1)) or (inputB(indice) and cout(indice-1));
        end loop;
end sum8bits;
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: A loop statement is a sequential statement. Statements found in an architecture body are concurrent statements. It appears you want to use a for generate statement (which requires a label). Add a label and replace loop with generate in two places (This appears to be a typographic error).

Comment: There's also an error in the second assignment statement to cout(indice) which will generate a bounds check error when indice = 7, the range of cout is (0 to 6). Use a [nested generate statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGP59.jpg), (also with a label).